# What is the difference between the Mercurial largefiles and lfs extensions?

Tags: mercurial, large-files

What are the differences (primarily from a workflow perspective) between the [largefiles](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/LargefilesExtension) and [lfs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/LfsPlan) extensions?

Answer (score 1):

The `largefiles` extension is part of Mercurial (and has been for many years). It is an "extension" in a technical sense, but in practice  since it is shipped as part of Mercurial that just means its an optional feature you have to enable via configuration if you want to use it.

LFS, as I understand it, is a proposal or work in progress. The page cited in the question hasn't been updated in > 3 years at this point, so perhaps work is no longer underway. And as stated on that page it is "...primarily intended for Mercurial's developers." which I take to mean that end users won't find anything useful for their day to day work.

Comment: Is [this patch](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2017-November/107727.html) the same as the lfs extension?

Comment: @Gili the LFS page mentions "the metadata format proposed by Git-LFS will be used" which seems like the same intent as the mailing list discussion. But a lot of time passed between the wiki writeup (2016) and that mailing list post (2017); I don't know if the 2017 implementation faithfully matched everything stated in the wiki.